# Convergence in the space of distributions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

If $g_1,g_2,g_3$ are each continuous functions and converge to a continuous function $g$. I am trying to show that for any test function $T$, we have that $\langle g_n, T\rangle$ converges to $\langle g,T \rangle$.

Here is what i have so far:

\begin{align*}
    \lim_{n\to\infty}\langle g_n, T \rangle &=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g_n(x)T(x)dx\\
    &=\int_{-N}^N g_n(x)T(x)dx\\
    &=\int_R\mathbf{1}_{[]-N,N]}g_n(x)T(x)
\end{align*}
I am not sure how to go from here (obviously I want the limit to somehow get inside the integral), I think here is where the continuity of the $(g_n)$ come in but I am unsure.

Comment: In which sense does $g_n \to g$ (pointwise or uniform)?

Comment: pointwise  convergence, although how would uniform convergence help?

Comment: $|\langle g_n,T \rangle - \langle g,T \rangle| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} |g_n(x)-g(x)||T(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x \leq M\int_{-N}^N |g_n-g|\,\mathrm{d}x$ where $M := \sup_{\mathbb{R}} |T|$. If $g_n \to g$ uniformly, then the integral clearly tends to $0$.

Comment: If the convergence is only pointwise, you'll likely need an additional assumption. For instance, assuming that the $g_n$ are uniformly bounded would help.

Comment: I suspect $\max(0,n(1-n|x-1/n|))$ (a $\wedge$ shaped function whose tip approaches $x=0$, and gets thinner as $n\to\infty$) shows that pointwise convergence does not guarantee the result

Comment: @rolandcyp, did you mean little "n" as the bounds of the integral? or else how is the big N dependent on the integrand?

Comment: @user593295 If $T$ is a test function, then $T$ is supported within $[-N,N]$ for some $N >0$ large. This is because test functions (by definition) have compact support.

Comment: @user593295 It's probably worth noting that we only need $g_n \to g$ *locally uniformly*. More generally,  if you only want to assume that $g_n \to g$ pointwise, it's enough for the $g_n$ to be bounded in $L^p([-N,N])$ for all $N > 0$ and *some* $1 < p < \infty$.